# Is it possible to run CSS3 animation step-by-step (one by one) for children?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

In a simple CSS3 animation with html ([EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AE7tj/))

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#">First</a>
    <a href="#">Second</a>
    <a href="#">Third</a>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim{
    0% {color:blue}
    10% {color:red}
}
.parent a {
    color:black;
    -webkit-animation: anim 3s infinite;
}
```

all change of color applies to all children at once. Is it possible to change the color for each child one by one?

In other words, we need to pause other children and run animation for a single child, then pausing and running the next child. This means only one child is animating at a time.

NOTE that the number of children is unknown, and we need to assign the animation duration for single child rather than the entire cycle.

Comment: Do you need a pure CSS solution ? It'd be far easier with some JS.

Comment: @mddw yes! I am curious if it is possible in CSS3 as it is easy with JS.

Comment: Well, `animation-delay` (http://jsfiddle.net/AE7tj/5/) will work, but not for a unknown number of child. I fear the answer to your question is "no", but maybe someone'll have a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS as it is. (Although in the future CSS-Variables may be available. Today they are only experimental though)

But you can create something (not very beautiful) with LESS or SASS (example below).
Note: You can do this only if you know the maximum amount of a that could be there.

```
@for $i from 1 through 19 {
    .parent a:nth-child(#{$i}) { -webkit-animation-duration: $1s; }
}
```

**Suggested solution:**
If you don't want to do that, use Javascript.
It's as simple as:

```
$.each($('.parent a'), function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).css('-webkit-animation-duration', index + 's');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/AE7tj/ this is the variant with animation-delay.

As @mddw said, it's possible to do, but with known number of children. Animation should be applied to every child, as everyone needs its own animation-delay.

Also, if you want animation to run infinite, you actually need animation-duration to cover the whole time. Animation-delay applies just for the first run of animation, and won't apply between iterations.

I have:

```
0% {color:blue}
33% {color:red}
66% {color: black}
100% {color: black}
```

And animation-duration is 9s. This means that from start to approx. 3rd second the color will change from blue to red, then from 3rd to 6th color will change from red to black, and stay black till the end of animation.